# MySQL JOIN working properly only when selecting every column with wildcard

Tags: mysql, join

This was probably asked a few times, but I couldn't find an answer. While doing JOIN on two tables, I encounter a problem. 
First table is named "Employees" and another "Orders". 
I'm trying to create a query, which will give me the output like:

**order_id** (from Orders) | **first_name** (from Employees) | **last_name** (from Employees)

The queries I use are:

```
SELECT * FROM Orders
LEFT JOIN Employees e on Orders.employeeid = e.EmployeeID;
```

or full join:

```
SELECT * FROM Orders
LEFT JOIN Employees e on Orders.employeeid = e.EmployeeID
UNION
SELECT * FROM Employees
RIGHT JOIN Orders o on Employees.EmployeeID = o.employeeid;
```

both work just fine, giving me the same results. Unless I select which columns I wish to extract. So query like that:

```
SELECT Orders.orderid, e.first_name, e.last_name FROM orders
LEFT JOIN Employees e on orders.employeeid = e.EmployeeID;
```

Gives me totally different results. Eg. first 100 orderids have same employee name, then another 100 different one and so on (only 4 employees overall, should be 9). 
What am I doing wrong?

EDIT (screenshots added):

Orders table:

[image]

Employees table:

[image]

Output when doing full join, everything seems to be ok:

[image]

Left join (or any other join, looks the same). Some orders seem to be ommited, but overall only 4 employees are listed.

[image]

Comment: Just changing * to column names isn't going to make a difference. Can you add sample data as text to the question please.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM Orders
LEFT JOIN Employees e on Orders.employeeid = e.EmployeeID;` ->> this query is giving you, your desired set of records and you wish to select data from the set of records retrieved by the query, right? Is this what you want?

Comment: Exactly, just orderid, FirstName and LastName.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know your data, but I think you want:

```
 SELECT o.orderid, e.first_name, e.last_name FROM orders o INNER JOIN Employees e ON o.employeeid = e.employeeId
 where o.employeeid != null
 Order by o.orderid
```

Comment: Both queries giving the same wrong results as the query I used.

Comment: Please try with  'and o.employeeid != null'

Comment: Ok let's try with order by.

Comment: My guess is that you may be seeing only the first 100 rows from the query, you could do a count on them and see if they return the same number

Comment: It works! Names that wasn't here are being shown now. Why did that happen by simply using order by?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176510/discussion-between-angry-somoan-and-tymtam).

Comment: `!= null` does not compute. Nothing is equal to null, nor not equal to null, not even null! The test for null is IS NULL

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without seeing some data samples.
But here are a few points:

With LEFT JOIN you get 'only 4 employees overall, should be 9' -- I assume there are 5 employees that do not have any order.

In the 'full join' you get mixed columns, the correct way should be

```
SELECT * FROM Orders
LEFT JOIN Employees e on Orders.employeeid = e.EmployeeID
UNION
SELECT * FROM Orders
RIGHT JOIN Employees e on Orders.employeeid = e.EmployeeID
```

Otherwise there should be no difference in the output if you specify the columns, as opposed to *.

Comment: Updated my post with screenshots. Still no luck.

Comment: 'Output when doing full join, everything seems to be ok:' -- scroll all the way to the end, don't you get employee names where ID's should be?

Comment: Last screenshot -- the output looks like it's sorted by employee id; is there an ORDER BY in your queries that you didn't mention?

Comment: There's no ORDER BY used in any of these queries. All the queries looks exactly like i wrote them in my question. Weird thing is, that both RIGHT JOIN and LEFT JOIN give me the same results... I don't understand the first question. Every order is assigned to the right employee. Just employeId is being shown twice.

Answer (score 0):

If

```
SELECT * FROM Orders
LEFT JOIN Employees e on Orders.employeeid = e.EmployeeID
```

is returning the correct set of results, then this should probably work:

```
Select orderid, FirstName, LastName from (SELECT * FROM Orders
LEFT JOIN Employees e on Orders.employeeid = e.EmployeeID LIMIT 999999) as joinedTable
```

Comment: [42S21][1060] (conn=448) Duplicate column name 'EmployeeID' [42S21][1060] Duplicate column name 'EmployeeID'

tymtam answer fixed that.